# interaction contrast with glmer

Tags: r, data-modeling, lme4, interaction

I am running a model with a similar structure:

```
model <- glmer(protest ~ factora*factorb*numeric+factora+factorb+numeric+1 + (1 + factor1|level1) + (1|level2), data=data, family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

where `factora` and `factorb` are factor variables, `numeric` is a numerical variable.

**I am curious of the statistical significance of the contrast in the interaction while holding `factora` constant at 3, between two values of `factorb` (1-5) across the range of the numerical value.**

I have tried the following options with no luck:

```
library(psycho)
get_contrasts(model, formula="factora:factorb:numeric", adjust="tukey")
View(contrasts$contrasts)
```

this works, but unfortunately the results hold `numeric` constant and only vary `factora` and `factorb`. Therefore, it does not answer my question.

I have also tried:

```
library(multcomp)
test = glht(model,linfct=mcp("factora:factorb:numeric"="Tukey"))
```

this yields the error of

```
Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : 
  Variable(s) ‘factora:factorb:numeric’ have been specified in ‘linfct’ but cannot be found in ‘model’!
```

without regard of the way I specify the interaction and despite other functions like `get_contrasts` finding the interaction specified the same way.

I have also tried:

```
library(emmeans)
contrast(m.3[[2]], interaction = c("factora", "factorb", "numeric"))
```

this however does not support glmer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here that are tripping you up.

One is that we don't really apply contrasts to numeric predictors. Numeric predictors have slopes, not contrasts; and if you have a model where a numeric predictor interacts with a factor, that means that the slope for the numeric predictor is different for each level of the factor. The function `emtrends()` in the **emmeans** package can help you estimate those different slopes.

The second is that the `interaction` argument in `emmeans::contrast()` needs a specification for the *type* of contrasts to use, e.g., `"pairwise"`. The factors to apply them to are those in the `emmGrid` object in the first argument.

So... I think maybe you want to try something like this:

```
emt <- emtrends(model, ~ factora*factorb, var = "numeric")
emt    # list the estimated slopes

contrast(emt, interaction = "consec")
    # obtain interaction contrasts comparing consecutive levels of the two factors
```

Comment: thanks! `emt` looks what I need, but the output of the `contrast` function is not very useful. I have changed the interaction to type `pairwise` since the contrast I am interested in is not between two consecutive levels of `factorb`.
Nevertheless, the problem is that it simultaneously varies `factora` and `factorb` so I don't know how to interpret the output. I need to hold `factora` constant and estimate the p value of the contrast between two values of `factorb` across the range of numeric (see the orig. post).

Comment: if someone is looking at this, I have managed with a simple adjustment:
`emt <- emtrends(model, ~ factorb | factora, var = "numeric")
emt    # list the estimated slopes
contrast(emt, interaction = "pairwise") # all contrasts, pairwise`

Comment: It doesn’t surprise me that this is what you want actually wanted. However, these results are no longer interaction contrasts, because they are only of one factor, conditionally on the other. So the interaction keyword in that call is unnecessary. Interaction contrasts are contrasts of contrasts, and in the example I gave, they break down the interaction effects into one-df components.